# How can I get rdp to maximise to just one of my monitor when already logged in as mstsc /span?

Tags: rdp, mstsc

I have 2 monitors at work and 2 monitors at home.

When I log into work from home using mstsc /span, my work desktop appears correctly spread across my 2 home monitors.

Then I want to open another RDP session on my work machine. When I maximise that window, it now fills both of my home monitors. How can I make it just fill the monitor it is on - like it would if I was at work and NOT using mstsc /span?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to edit the file "default.rdp" created in your Documents forder.. You need to add a setting for "selectedmonitors:s:x,y,z,*".
If you want to know which number is your monitor, execute "mstsc /l" in ms-doc command.

As seen on 
https://remotedesktop.uservoice.com/forums/266795-remote-desktop-services/suggestions/18010924-allow-ability-to-choose-subset-of-local-monitors-f

Scott Hanselman also answered inside a comment with his own blog. his solution is very detailed:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRemoteDesktopFullscreenRDPWithJustSOMEOfYourMultipleMonitors.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I'll suggest an answer now anyway in case someone lands up here.

It seems to me that to solve this problem there is no need for `selectedmonitors` in the RDP file. Instead of using `/span` to connect to work you should be using `/multimon`.

`/span` creates one big "screen" across your two home monitors. So when you go "fullscreen" in your work session it goes across them.
`/multimon` makes your work computer aware of your two-monitor setup. When you maximise a window or go full-screen it will do so in the way you'd expect.

As I have found recently, `selectedmonitors` could be useful if your primary monitor at home is not the one which you want to consider the primary in your work session.